# SIGHUP: failed for SignalException with script/runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nohup

Hi I am trying to run a script/runner process which failed because of SignalException: SIGHUP:

The process nearly takes 4-5hrs. Can someone please let me know what exactly is happening and what would be a work around.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shell the process was started from is dying. You can either disown the process from the calling shell or call it with `nohup`, which will cause the process to ignore SIGHUPs.

Something like `nohup script/runner "YourCodeHere.run" &` would make the script/runner task impervious to SIGHUPs.

Edit: Say you ssh into a server. You'll spawn a new shell (running /bin/bash would work similarly). If you drop connection, the shell you started with ssh also dies. When it does, it sends SIGHUP to all of the attached processes. SIGHUP is a UNIX signal. [There are a few of them](http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm). Another you're probably (perhaps unknowingly) familiar with is SIGINT, which is what is sent to the process when you hit ctrl-c.

Comment: This happened me when I ran a rake task on heroku. So addind `nohup` before the task solved the issue for me.